# How long do Cmdlet instances persist?

Tags: powershell

Was interested in what a custom implementation of a derived Cmdlet would look like, really to see how much work was involved.  Mocked up the following:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace EMSEngineering
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "Cmdlet")]
    public class TestCmdlet : Cmdlet
    {
        static int nextIndex = 0;

        private int index = nextIndex;

        public TestCmdlet()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("instantiating {0}", index);
            nextIndex++;
        }

        ~ TestCmdlet()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("terminating {0}", index);
        }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public string[] SomeParameter { get; set; }

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            if (SomeParameter != null)
                WriteVerbose(string.Format("begin processing {0} params", SomeParameter.Length));
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            foreach (string param in SomeParameter)
                WriteObject(string.Format("processing {0}", param));
        }

        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            if (SomeParameter != null)
                WriteVerbose(string.Format("end processing {0} params", SomeParameter.Length));
        }

        protected override void StopProcessing()
        {
            WriteVerbose("stop processing");
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy here, but when calling at the prompt, I noticed something unexpected.

> PS E:\users\bitbucket\crmcall\Build_PI> '1','2' | Test-Cmdlet
> instantiating 0
> processing 1
> processing 2
> PS E:\users\bitbucket\crmcall\Build_PI> '1','2' | Test-Cmdlet
> instantiating 1
> processing 1
> processing 2
> PS E:\users\bitbucket\crmcall\Build_PI> exit
> terminating 1
> terminating 0

Each call to my little mock Cmdlet spun up a new instance.  They only terminated when I exited the shell.  I tried this within a larger loop where this was repeated 10 or more times.  Same result - new instance on each call and all terminated on shell exit.

Is this the case for all Cmdlets?
Do they really just stack up until the shell is exited?
Have I missed something in my implementation?

Comment: Yes. ;-) A newly created cmdlet or function only exists in the scope of the current session. If you want to make it available for later use you will have to save it in a module or script file or you could put it in your profile.

Comment: Apologies, I don't believe I was clear.  I'm asking in terms of memory usage of the current shell.  It seems over time, and with lots of repeated Cmdlet calls within tight loops, instances would stack up consuming more and more memory.  Is there a mechanism for terminating an instance sooner?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. If you create the same cmdlet again and again you actually overwrite it every time you *define* it.

Comment: That doesn't match the output, though.  The instance member 'index' shows that each instance is unique and that instances are building up over time, one per call.  I tried this in a larger loop and the output showed 10 unique instances, all of them persisting until the shell was exited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Indeed, every call to a cmdlet creates a *new instance* of the implementing .NET class.
- These instances are *eventually* garbage-collected (the timing is not deterministic and it can take *minutes* until collection occurs), but you can force *synchronous* disposal by invoking [the .NET garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.GC) explicitly:

  ```sh
  [GC]::Collect(); [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
  ```

Note:

- By default, the garbage collector runs *periodically*, and, as stated, it can take minutes until a given object is actually freed; however, the garbage collector also runs *on demand*, in low-memory situations, and even the frequency of the periodic runs is dependent on memory conditions (another way of putting it: there is no *fixed* frequency)  - see the [Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) help topic for more information.

  - To give one example of the variability of the frequency: *shortly after entering* a PowerShell session the memory pressure is apparently higher, making near-instant garbage collection more likely.
- In *some* situations garbage collection of cmdlet-implementing instances happens *instantly*:

  - If you invoke help via `-?`: `Test-Cmdlet -?` (though *not* via `Get-Help Test-Cmdlet`, which doesn't necessitate instantiating the cmdlet class).
  - If the invocation is *syntactically invalid*, such as when attempting to use an unknown parameter; e.g.: `Test-Cmdlet -NosuchParam`
  - Others?

Comment: @ChrisMcAllister, as for formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks, and you cannot double `\`` instances - use `\\`` to embed `\``.

Comment: @ChrisMcAllister, as for your question: please see my update.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I tested both of those scenarios, but actually the same behavior holds true.  The constructor is called, but not the terminator.  The instances persist until either a subsequent call to **[GC]::Collect()** or the shell is exited.

Comment: @ChrisMcAllister: It makes sense that when the process _as a whole_ terminates (exiting a PowerShell instance) that it must release its memory and that garbage collection therefore runs, but I only see the console output from the finalizers _intermittently_ when exiting a (nested) _interactive_ PowerShell session, and _never_ when using the `-File` / `-Command` CLI parameters. I'm only speculating, but this _may_ just be a case of the `System.Console.WriteLine()` call in the finalizer situationally no longer working when the entire process is terminating.